# Differenciate views from tables in Schema.getTables()

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

I'm using jOOQ's [Schema.getTables()](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.5.2/org/jooq/Schema.html) method to find all the tables from my schema, but I found this method also returns the views. Checking at the returned [Table](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.5.2/org/jooq/Table.html) objects I don't see a way to identify if it was a table or a view in my schema.

What is the proper way of selecting only the views using jOOQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jOOQ currently doesn't have a way to distinguish between:

- Tables
- Temporary tables
- Partitioned tables
- Table hierarchies
- Object tables
- Views
- Materialised views
- Functions
- Others

This is on the roadmap for a future jOOQ version:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2370

There's no simple workaround in the jOOQ API itself. You could run a query on PostgreSQL's dictionary views, however:

```sql
SELECT table_schema, table_name, table_type
FROM information_schema.tables
```